# grid layout widget goes off the screen

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

When I add listView to my GridLayout it goes out of the screen.
ListView should fill whole space between TextView and bottom of the screen.
Bellow is example of code (I have to use grid layout because in my concrete situation there is a multi column/rows layout).

I'm new in Android. Thank you.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:id="@+id/gridSearchAuthors"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="1"
android:padding="4dp"
android:rowCount="2" >    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/q"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:text="Hledaný výraz: " />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_row="1" />

</GridLayout>
```

[Image of Layout in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYfQ9.png)

Comment: Are you using custom adapter for listview?

Comment: Yes. I've solved my issue with combination of grid and linear layout.(for complex header I used grid layout that is placed to linear layout with list view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `LinearLayout` instead of `GridLayout`.

Use custom adapter for listview population if you have a complex layout.